# How to keep on parent hover width when acces child dropdown and try to select element in it

Tags: html, css

This is my first post here and I really hope, that someone could help me. I search a lot on internet but I didn't found anything usefull.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#box').hover(
         function () {
           $(this).animate({left:"+=180px"}, "fast");
         },
         function () {
           $(this).animate({left:"-=180px"}, "slow");
         }
     );

   });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:900px;position: absolute;left:-180px; width:200px;">
<div id="skinDiv">
    <select name="skin">
    <option value="">[ None ]</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm working on a web page and I want to have menu in the left which will be animated. When user want to select something from menu he can hover it and menu will came from left side of monitor to specific page e.g. +200px to left. User will have there dropdown, where he could select something from it.

Problem is, that when user focus on this html select element eg on list element parent div lose focus and user can't select anything from dropdown, because dropdown also hides.

I hope that I was clear, if not I will try to explain more.

I hope, that you could help me on problem, because I try to solve this for a days, but with no success.

Regards,
Miha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#handle').mouseenter(slideIn);
    $("#box").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: "-=180px"
        }, "slow");
        $('#handle').mouseenter(slideIn);
    });
    $("[name='skin']").mouseleave(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});

function slideIn() {
    if ($("#box")) $("#box").animate({
        left: "+=180px"
    }, "fast");
    $(this).unbind("mouseenter");
}
```

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/PRZYN/

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! This is exacly what I want and I finaly solve my problem!! Thanks you again very much!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your jquery. Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#box').mouseenter(function () {
       $(this).animate({left:"+=180px"}, "fast");
     }).
     mouseleave(function () {
       $(this).animate({left:"-=180px"}, "slow");
     });

 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTXXH/2/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. I have already try exact code a few hours ago, but It didn't work. If I try to select option "Red" from dropdown the div lost focus and it tries to hide(eg. execute this commang: $(this).animate({left:"-=180px"}, "slow");). There is reason why I want to solve this problem, that user could select something from list and that animation stay on my page.

Comment: Problem was in jquery. You were right! Thank you for your help, I appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css also if u want, without using jQuery.

CSS:

```
#box{
background:#98bf21;
height:900px;
position: absolute;
left:-180px; 
width:200px;
    transition: left 2s;
    -moz-transition: left 2s;
    -webkit-transition: left 2s;
    -o-transition: left 2s;
}
#box:hover{
left: 0px;
}

#box:hover div{
left:100px;
display:block;
}
#skinDiv{
position:relative;
}
```

see demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd9rB/4/)

Comment: I did think of this option too, but I want to do my code as simple as it can be. And also I had some compatibility issues with older browsers...

Comment: well it runs at most of browsers except IE and also u don't have to load the jquery javascript only for that.

Comment: I will use jquery on some other elements so this will not be only case. Also I will have some other divs inside of mayor manu div so I am not sure how good will run this...

Comment: Thanks also to you to help on my problem. I appreciate this and I am happy, that there exist people who help to others! Thanks again for your help. Regards,Miha